# WPF Datagrid nested property-shows empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I used to think that WPF supports nested properties with a ., but somehow it shows empty
Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="storageGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="351" Width="643">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Product.Name}" Width="100" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="100" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

When the form is loaded, I call the InitializeData method, that looks like this:

```
    public void InitializeData()
    {
        storageGrid.Items.Clear();

        var dbStorages = Repository.Storages();
        foreach (var storage in dbStorages)
        {
            Storages.Add(storage);
        }
        storageGrid.ItemsSource = Storages;
        storageGrid.Items.Refresh();

    }
```

Storages is a local List property. I'm using Entity Framework Databse First classes, here's the Storage definition:

```
public partial class Storage
{
    public Nullable<int> ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoomId { get; set; }
    public int EntryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
}
```

When I launch the app, here's the picture I see:
[image: WPF DataGrid shows the property correctly, but the nested property is empty]

How do I make DataGrid show the nested Product's Name?

Comment: What type is `Storages` of?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg List<Storage>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lazy loading, so I needed to add an Include statement to my Repository.Storages() method like this:

```
return ctx.Storages.Include(s => s.Product).ToList();
```

I also needed to add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

so that I get an Include extension method with lambda